# Why is my ManyToManyField in Django returning only one value?

Tags: django, many-to-many

In my Django project, I have a class with a ManyToManyField:

```
class ContestCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)
    judges = models.ManyToManyField('users.CustomUser', null=True)
```

I can see after migrating that everything worked fine and the table is created. I made a form to change the judges like this:

```
class JudgesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ContestCategory
        fields = ['judges']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(JudgesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my view, the form appears and correctly displays all the CustomUser objects there are, and shows no error when saving. However, in my post method, when I do this:

```
class SubmissionCategoriesDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = ContestCategory
    template_name = 'reportes/detail_submission_categories.html'
    form_class = JudgesForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):# 1711   5656    2230400    7616
        pk_category = kwargs.get('pk')
        judges = request.POST.get('judges')

        logging.info(str(judges))

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('reportes:submission_categories'))
```

I get in the logs that 'judges' returns the correct Id of my CustomUser but only if I have just one CustomUser selected. Whenever I choose more than one, it only gives me in 'judges' the Id of the last one that was chosen, not of all of them.

Why is this happening? Should I use a different widget than the automatic one or is there something missing from the models? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a [**`request.POST.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) always returns one value. If you want to return *all* values, you should make use of [**`request.POST.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist):

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class SubmissionCategoriesDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = ContestCategory
    template_name = 'reportes/detail_submission_categories.html'
    form_class = JudgesForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk_category = kwargs.get('pk')
        judges = request.POST.getlist('judges')

        logging.info(str(judges))

        return redirect('reportes:submission_categories')
```

It is however better to use the form to process the data:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class SubmissionCategoriesDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = ContestCategory
    template_name = 'reportes/detail_submission_categories.html'
    form_class = JudgesForm

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = JudgesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            logging.info(str(form.cleaned_data['judges']))

        return redirect('reportes:submission_categories')
```

You might want to take a look at an [**`UpdateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView) to handle the boilerplate logic.